# Why does the loop direction of my filter change my result?

Tags: c++, vivado, vivado-hls

I have designed a simple dual channel filter to remove some noise at a given frequency.

```
#include "../include/Filter.h"

void Filter(int DataIn, int* DataOut, bool Enable)
{
    static coef_t Coefficients[] = {
            0.0076925293, -0.039817952, 0.018740745, 0.013075141, -0.052312399,
            0.052374545, 0.017044802, -0.14227364, 0.26541378, 0.68194015, 0.26541378,
            -0.14227364, 0.017044802, 0.052374545, -0.052312399, 0.013075141, 0.018740745,
            -0.039817952, 0.0076925293
    };

    static data_t ShiftRegRight[LENGTH];
    static data_t ShiftRegLeft[LENGTH];

    acc_t AccRight = 0x00;
    acc_t AccLeft = 0x00;

    if(Enable == true)
    {
        Shift_Accum_Loop: for(int i = (LENGTH - 1); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                ShiftRegRight[0] = DataIn & 0x0000FFFF;
                ShiftRegLeft[0] = (DataIn & 0xFFFF0000) >> 0x10;
            }
            else
            {
                ShiftRegRight[i] = ShiftRegRight[i - 1];
                ShiftRegLeft[i] = ShiftRegLeft[i - 1];
            }

            AccRight += ShiftRegRight[i] * Coefficients[i];
            AccLeft += ShiftRegLeft[i] * Coefficients[i];
        }

        *DataOut = ((AccLeft.range() >> 0x20) << 0x10) | (AccRight.range() >> 0x20);
    }
    else
    {
        *DataOut = DataIn;
    }
}
```

This filter produce the following output on a given test signal:

```
0, 0, 0
1, 28377, 218
2, 0, 64405
3, 0, 531
4, 0, 370
5, 37159, 63833
6, 0, 2616
7, 37159, 65269
8, 0, 62257
9, 0, 8484
10, 0, 17494
11, 28377, 8750
12, 0, 62919
13, 28377, 58754
14, 0, 50948
15, 0, 48035
16, 0, 52449
17, 37159, 56833
18, 0, 0
19, 37159, 8484
20, 0, 14216
21, 0, 16968
22, 0, 14216
...
```

The test signal is generated with a testbench:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "../include/Filter.h"

#define SAMPLES                 48000
#define FREQ_RIGHT_1            8000
#define FREQ_RIGHT_2            10000
#define FREQ_LEFT_1             50

FILE* File;

int main(void)
{
    int Output;
    int StreamData;
    uint16_t RightChannel = 0x00;
    uint16_t LeftChannel = 0x00;

    File = fopen("Result.log", "w");
    for(int i = 0x00; i < SAMPLES; i++)
    {
        // Generate the input data
        RightChannel = 32767 * sin(2 * M_PI * i / (SAMPLES / FREQ_RIGHT_1)) * sin(2 * M_PI * i / (SAMPLES / FREQ_RIGHT_2));
        StreamData = (LeftChannel << 0x10) | RightChannel;

        // Execute the function with latest input
        Filter(StreamData, &Output, true);

        // Write the simulation results
        fprintf(File, "%i, %d, %d\n", i, StreamData, Output);
    }

    fclose(File);
}
```

So why do I get a different output, when I change the `for` loop in `Filter` from a down counting loop into a upcounting loop?

```
if(Enable == true)
{
    Shift_Accum_Loop: for(int i = 0; i < (LENGTH - 1); i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            ...

0, 0, 0
1, 28377, 27073
2, 0, 0
3, 0, 0
4, 0, 0
5, 37159, 38462
6, 0, 0
7, 37159, 38462
8, 0, 0
9, 0, 0
10, 0, 0
11, 28377, 27073
```

What is the difference between this? The loops do count from `0` to `(LENGTH - 1)` in both cases and the filter is symetric. Why does the count direction has an impact on the result?

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but what is the `Shift_Accum_Loop` label for? Are you planning on using `goto`? Then don't. If you have it as a "comment" about the loop, then please write a proper comment instead, which explains what the loop does and why the loop does it that way.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to step through the different implementations of the loop, statement by statement, in a debugger? And think about an assignment like `ShiftRegRight[i] = ShiftRegRight[i - 1];`, and what the initial values of the `ShiftRegRight` array might be.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the label is just for the HLS directives and not for some sort of `goto` or stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(i == 0)
        {
            ShiftRegRight[0] = DataIn & 0x0000FFFF;
            ShiftRegLeft[0] = (DataIn & 0xFFFF0000) >> 0x10;
        }
        else
        {
            ShiftRegRight[i] = ShiftRegRight[i - 1];
            ShiftRegLeft[i] = ShiftRegLeft[i - 1];
        }
```

When you count down `i==0` evaluates to true last.

When you count up `i==0` evaluates to true first.